# Do AMD apps load faster than CommonJS apps in the browser?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, amd, commonjs

I have read quite a lot on those two subjects, but they still confuse me. From what I understand, AMD is generally a better choice for front-end applications, since it handles asynchronicity better. Does that mean that AMD applications are faster? Why are AMD modules better suited for browsers?

Comment: The code ends up running at the same speed. But it may load faster (at first) running AMD than anything else since it requests scripts as it needs them rather than loading them all up front.

Comment: You are right, I was talking about the loading (I changed my question). But then why do people use things like Browserify if it's slower?

Comment: Because the speed difference is usually in micro-milliseconds and running AMD is a much bigger pain in the neck than using CommonJS with Browserify (at least that's my opinion and the opinion of many people around the Internet)

Comment: Isn't it the same than using RequireJs with AMD?

Comment: RequireJS follows much the same idea as AMD but it (usually) isn't bundled using something like Browserify. CommonJS and RequireJS are different.

Comment: I was comparing RequireJS and browserify.

Comment: Then it's just like comparing AMD and Browserify. Same idea, different setup.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. What I'm saying is why is Browserify/CommonJS less of a pain than RequireJS/AMD? Anyway, you can post the answer, thanks!

Comment: This question is going to get closed because it's all a matter of opinion. I find Browserify easier because I don't need to configure a loader and I don't need to define all of my code inside of these weird little asynchronous blocks. Doing `var myModule = require('./my-module.js')` is just simple and makes sense to me. I prefer that over AMD/RequireJS syntax.

Comment: You have already answered the question anyway: "It's faster, but not enough to be taken into consideration", this is just an extra because I was curious :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Mike C, an application using AMD modules will load faster than an application using CommonJS modules, but the difference is in micro-milliseconds.